# phpmailer with calendar event and pdf attachement

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send email using PHP Mailer. I am attaching pdf file , embeded calendar event and also calendar attachment(.ics) but i am not able to send both in a single mail.

If i comment PDF attachment code, email will go with embeded calendar event and .ics attachment.

Code for the PDF attachment:

```
  $mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf_content,$name,'base64','application/pdf');
```

Code for the embeded calendar event

```
$i_calendar="BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:".$start_timestamp."
DTEND:".$end_timestamp."
DTSTAMP:".$start_timestamp."
ORGANIZER;CN=".$rest_name.":mailto:".$from_email."
UID:".$ics_reservation_id."
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=".$customer_name.":mailto:".$cust_email."
DESCRIPTION:test
LOCATION:".$restaurant_city."
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Reservation
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"; 

$text = $i_calendar;
```

and adding this variable to

```
$mail->AltBody = $text; 
$mail->Ical = $text;
```

What should be the header for the mail ?

How to send single mail with both attachments and embeded calendar event ?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: It would help if you explained what happens when you do try sending both; do you get an error? A bounceback? Is the email going through but invalid in some way? Have you tried with only the PDF?

Comment: hi andrew, i have edited the question to brief on my problem. You can go through the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// ... other PHPMailer options

$mail->addAttachment('/pdf_file.pdf');
$mail->addAttachment('/calendar_file.ics');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    // Error
} else {
    // Success
}
?>
```

In case you really need to embed it in the e-mail, then use the following (I didn't tested this code):

```
  <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// ... other PHPMailer options

$mail->addStringAttachment($pdf_string, 'pdf_file.pdf');
$mail->addStringAttachment($ics_string, 'calendar_file.ics');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    // Error
} else {
    // Success
}
?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54125/discussion-between-andrew-barber-and-wissam-el-kik).

Comment: Hi Wissam, i have tried with your second code ie embed calendar event in the e-mail and email is going with attachments ie pdf attachment and .ics attachment. But its not displaying calendar event inside the mail content. I want to display calendar event inside the mail content with attachments.

Comment: If you want the files embedded in the e-mail, then you should use the following function "addStringAttachment". The ".ics" format is not part of a "known MimeType", as mentioned here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm
The browser won't recognize the iCalendar and it won't load properly in most of the e-mail clients (and browsers).

Answer (score 0):

There is [a problem with PHPMailer and proper iCal/ics support](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175) (not least that outlook and gmail can't agree). The correct fix involves major changes to PHPMailer's MIME structures that's not going to happen any time soon, so you'll need to compromise. you could deal with it by using a separate MIME structure builder (such as [Zend_MIME](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mime.html)) and either use Zend_Mail to send it, or just use it to set the message body in PHPMailer.